# In R, Create new dataframe using rows thave have a certain characteristic

Tags: r

I am playing around with some data for March Madness, and I am trying to create new dataframes in R that would split everything that is "AP" into one dataframe and everything that is "DUN" into a different frame. It is a huge dataset, but that is a slice that illustrates what I wnat to do, I just can't figure it out in R any help would be much appreciated.

```
H,37,AP,662,18
H,37,AP,783,19
H,37,AP,636,20
H,37,AP,671,21
H,37,AP,708,22
H,37,AP,562,23
H,37,AP,675,24
H,37,AP,554,25
H,37,DUN,625,1
H,37,DUN,717,2
H,37,DUN,577,3
H,37,DUN,511,4
H,37,DUN,676,5
```

Bonus points if someone can tell me how to use this to delete certain rows based off a column (delete all 625s from column 4.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seeing that you used the word "split" in your question, did you try the `split` function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split()` to create a list of data frames for each factor:

```
split(df, by = factor(df$AP_or_DUN))
```

To remove rows based on a certain value, say `num`, in a certain column, say `i`, you can subset using `[`, *i.e.*:

```
df <- df[df[, i] != num, ]
```

or, if the column has a name:

```
df <- df[df$column_of_values != num, ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use `dlply` from the `plyr` package.  It returns your data in a list of of data frames, but if you want to keep them together, it may help.

```
dat <- colA colB colC colD colE
          H   37   AP  675   24
          H   37   AP  554   25
          H   37  DUN  625    1
          H   37  DUN  717   25

dat2 <- dlply(dat, .(colC))

$AP
  colA colB colC colD colE
1    H   37   AP  675   24
2    H   37   AP  554   25

$DUN
  colA colB colC colD colE
1    H   37  DUN  625    1
2    H   37  DUN  717    2

for (i in 1:length(dat2)) 
  assign(names(dat2)[i], dat2[[i]])
```